# How can I give rank to dates?

Tags: sql, ranking, rank

I have an orders table with `USER_ID` and `ORDER_DATE`
I want to achieve somthing like this:

```
SELECT [USER_ID], [FIRST_ORDER_DATE], [SECOND_ORDER_DATE], 
       [THIRD_ORDER_DATE], [FOURTH_ORDER_DATE]
FROM ORDERS
```

I have tried to create a scalar function (`getFirstOrder`, `getSecondOrder`, ...) 
but after the third its very slow

any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: This may be helpful : http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/creating-cross-tab-queries-and-pivot-tables-in-sql/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this:

```
select user_id, 
       max(case when rnk = 1 then date_col else null end) as first_order_date,
       max(case when rnk = 2 then date_col else null end) as second_order_date,
       max(case when rnk = 3 then date_col else null end) as third_order_date
from (
     select user_id, 
            date_col,
            dense_rank() over (partition by user_id order by date_col) as rnk
     from orders
) t
group by user_id;
```

You didn't specify your DBMS. The above is ANSI SQL that works on most modern DBMS.